# Android Development tools logcats bad characters

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

i installed android development tools(ADT Build: v22.2.1-833290) in Linux Ubuntu 13.10(Ubuntu gnome) but i have an unexpected problem. tha characters of logcats doesn't show properly and i cant read logcat data. i take an screenshot of that. how i can fix it?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: first isolate if its eclipse problem or logcat. use command adt logcat and see if you can see these messages in command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the problem. it was because of logcat default font that was not an standard font. i changed t from settings